# RSS Feed "Delete" Signal

Tags: wordpress, rss

I've been using the RSS feed of my personal site to export its posts to a Wordpress installation, using the plugin FeedWordPress.

In its current state, when a post is deleted from my personal site, it also disappears from the RSS feed, but remains on the Wordpress installation (an undesirable behavior). There is an option in the FeedWordPress plugin to retain only the posts that are currently in the RSS, but then I have a different problem, because only the latest 50 entries are stored in the RSS at any time, so older posts would be deleted as well.

The most promising lead for a solution came from another option for the plugin, which goes:

> Allow Feeds to Delete Posts:   Yes. If a feed indicates that one of its
>   posts has been deleted,  delete the local copy syndicated to this
>   website.

How would I go about adding such a deletion indication/signal in my RSS feed?

Comment: I ran into trouble searching on Google because of the abundance of articles talking about how to "delete posts from an rss feed". Any ideas for keywords I could use to narrow down my search would also be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was referring to tombstones (deleted-entry elements) in Atom.

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6721

Answer (score 0):

I would use the built in option in feedpress or create a category and add the unwanted posts there and exclude them from the feed.